# javascript code analysis: getting the name of handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, analysis

I am to analyse a huge js script. I'm using deobfuscators and firebug, but this script is so complicated that it's difficult for me to understand anything. So my question is do you know any tool that would show me e.g. name of function that handles event I fire? Or maybe it's possible to write it myself?

Comment: Refactoring is often better than any tools.

Comment: _“any tool that would show me e.g. name of function that handles event I fire?”_ – that function does not need to have a “name” …

Comment: @CBroe does not need, but could have. in my case often has

Answer (score 1):

Try (this pattern)

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click.abc", "body", function def (e) {
        var name = (e.handleObj.handler.name === "" 
                    ? "<i>event handler name:</i> " + "anonymous function"
                    : "<i>event handler name:</i> "+ e.handleObj.handler.name);
        var namespace =  (e.handleObj.namespace 
                          ? "<i>event namespace:</i> " + e.handleObj.namespace 
                          : "<i>event namespace:</i> " + e.handleObj.namespace);
        $("body").append("<br>" 
                         + "<i>event type:</i> " 
                         + e.type + "\n" 
                         + name + "\n" 
                         + namespace);
        $.each($._data($(document)[0], "events"), function(k, v) {
          console.log(k
                      , v[0].data
                      , v[0].guid
                      , v[0].handler.name
                      , v[0].namespace
                      , v[0].origType
                      , v[0].selector
                      , v[0].type);
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ykcnbuqp/